# random.randint() call with -1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Can someone explain why the `range` in the `random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)` has a minus 1 at the end? The list has 9 values:

```
import random

messages = ['It is certain',
            'It is decidedly so',
            'Yes definitely',
            'Reply hazy try again',
            'Ask again later',
            'Concentrate and ask again',
            'My reply is no',
            'Outlook not so good',
            'Very doubtful']

select_number = random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)
list_select  = messages[select_number]
print(list_select)
```

Comment: It would help if you'd elaborate why exactly this strikes you as odd.

Comment: Because it was written by someone who isn't very familiar with Python? Maybe they did a straight translation of code from another language. The sensible way would be to use `random.choice`, or staying closer to the original, `select_number = random.randrange(len(messages))`

Comment: Ironically, `randint` was a late addition to `random`, for the people who found `randrange` confusing. But if someone has problems with `randrange` how do they cope with `range`, or slice notation?

Answer (score 1):

`random.randint()`'s second value is **inclusive**. It'll pick a number from *10* random integers (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` and `9`), where you only have 9 indices in the list. `len(messages)` is `9`, but there is no `messages[9]` index, as Python indexing starts at `0`. Instead, the only valid indices go from `0` to `8`.

So by using `random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)`, the function is limited to picking a valid index for the `messages` list.

The code should instead use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice), which picks a random element from a list:

```
list_select = random.choice(messages)
```

In other situations, [`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.range) could be an option too, as it doesn't include the endpoint in the possible values, working analogous to Python indexing, slicing and `range()`:

```
index_select = random.randrange(len(messages))
```

Comment: Won't picking an index at random via `random.randint` and choosing that element, versus using `random.choice` to pick an element from the list, be the same thing?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: yes, the end result is the same. But `random.choice()` lets you avoid errors more easily, and is cleaner and clearer when reading back the code.

Comment: Makes sense, I assume the internal logic of `random.choice` might be using `random.randint` in a way!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: No, it uses an internal `_rand_below` method, see [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L285-L291).

Answer (score 0):

This is because `random.randint` picks  the indexes of the list, from 0 to 8 at random, and selects a message.
Now, the indexes of a list goes from `0` to `len(messages)-1=8`.
According to the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

> random.randint(a, b) . 
>   Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1).

Which means an integer between 0 and 8 is picked, which are the valid indexes of the list, If we have instead put `len(messages)`, index 9 would have been picked too which is an invalid index for a list in Python, since Python lists are `0-indexed`

Answer (score 0):

`random.randint(a, b)` *Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.*

`len(messages) - 1` Is a bit tricky because range of your list is indeed 9 but you have to remember that counting is starting from 0 instead of 1. So in your case `len(messages)` is going to return 9 but the first element is in `messages[0]`

It means that in your case the `select_number = random.randint(0, len(messages) - 1)` will give number from 0 to `len(messages) - 1` which is 9 - 1.